# Is there a shortcut for specifying multiple related namespaces in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a shortcut or trick for specifying multiple related namespaces in XAML?

Imagine if you are using a UI library and it has the following namespaces:

```
TheCompany.TheProduct.TheCommonNamespace.Controls
TheCompany.TheProduct.TheCommonNamespace.Framework
TheCompany.TheProduct.TheCommonNamespace.Dialogs
```

If I want to use all 3 of them in a single XAML, do I need to declare 3 different xmlns's?

There's no way to do something like `TheCompany.TheProduct.TheCommonNamespace.*`? (which obviously doesn't work).

The library (which I wrote) does put the namespaces in the AssemblyInfo.cs using XmlnsDefinitions and it has worked thus far... but I'm not sure its a good idea and now that I'm adding a "next generation" set of controls, some of the names will conflict.

For example I might have:

```
MyCompany.Controls.Flat.Button
MyCompany.Controls.NextGen.Button
```

I don't know if really want to start naming stuff FlatButton, FlatCheckBox, NextGenButton, NextGenCheckbox, etc.

But since both namespaces are added to the AssemblyInfo, the names would be ambiguous if I use just Button.

What is a good approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Go with specific naming of your controls. In this way there will no be ambiguity with what is what. You can still use namespaces for your classes and add everything in AssemblyInfo.cs